# PyQt5 Stylesheet For QWidget's Child To Change QWidget

Tags: pyqt5, children, qtstylesheets

I have a `QWidget` with a `HBoxLayout` inside. Inside this `HBoxLayout` there is a few buttons and a `QLineEdit` object. Using stylesheets, I would like to make it so that when the `QLineEdit` is focused, the `QWidget` gets a blue outline/border.

I have tried:

```py
QSearchWidgetStyleSheet = QWidget {background-color: rgb(27,27,27); border: none; margin: 0px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 0px;}
                          QLineEdit:focus {border: 3px solid rgb(100,100,100;}
```

With my `QLineEdit` stylesheet being:

```py
QLineEditStyleSheet = QLineEdit {color: white; background-color: rgb(255,255,255,0); border: none; height: 32px; border-radius: 3px; margin-left: 3px; margin-right: 3px;}
```

However, there is no effect on the `QWidget` when the `QLineEdit` is focussed. What should I change in order for the `QWidget` to get the border/outline when the `QLineEdit` is focused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QLineEdit:focus` applies the style to the QLineEdit, not the QWidget. While child widgets can take up the style sheet of their parent widget, I don't think it works the other way around in general style sheet syntax. Instead you could describe the scenario only considering the QWidget... It should have a border when it is not in focus, and it should not have a border when it is in focus.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(QPushButton('Push'))
        hbox.addWidget(QLineEdit())
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
        Widget {
            border: 3px solid blue;
        }
        Widget:focus {
            border: none;
        }''')

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.setFocus()


class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(Widget(), 0, 0)
        self.resize(300, 300)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Template()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Of course if you're open to using other methods, like signals and slots, you could achieve more precisely that functionality.